# Can Print no longer access certain values during evaluation?

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, evaluation, printing

This example from Power Programming in Mathematica doesn't work for me anymore: the values used for rootfinding are not printed during evaluation. What changed? Is there a new way to reproduce the old behavior?
[image]

Comment: As shown in the documentation, `FindRoot[Sin[x] - Cos[x], {x, 0.5}, EvaluationMonitor :> Print["x = ", x]]`

Answer (score 2):

It's not `Print` but `FindRoot` that has changed its behavior. `FindRoot` now evaluates its argument symbolically and uses the result to find the root, instead of the original argument.  Here are a few ways to reproduce the output in the book, except for the initial `x`:

```
FindRoot[Print[x]; Cos[x] - Sin[x],
 {x, 0.5},
 Evaluated -> False, Jacobian -> {{-Cos[x] - Sin[x]}}]
(*
0.5
0.793408
0.785398
0.785398

{x -> 0.785398}
*)

obj // ClearAll;
obj[x_?NumericQ] := (Print[x]; Cos[x] - Sin[x]);
obj /: obj' = -Sin[#] - Cos[#] &;
FindRoot[obj[x], {x, 0.5}]
(*
0.5
0.793408
0.785398
0.785398

{x -> 0.785398}
*)

FindRoot[
 If[x \[Element] Reals, Print[x]; Cos[x] - Sin[x]], 
 {x, 0.5}, 
 Jacobian -> {{-Cos[x] - Sin[x]}}]
(*
0.5
0.793408
0.785398
0.785398

{x -> 0.785398}
*)
```

You need to provide the derivative so the `FindRoot` will use the same method as in the book (Newton's with a symbolic Jacobian/derivative). The goal in the examples above is to supply an argument that when evaluated symbolically, it doesn't evaluate to a `Print`-less expression.  Note `Evaluated -> False`, which suppress evaluation of the argument, also prevents the automatic construction of the Jacobian; hence the `Jacobian` option.

I'm pretty sure this goes back a ways, well before [version-13](/questions/tagged/version-13) (as the question is currently tagged).

Comment: You can add a def, `obj[x_] := Null /; (Print[x]; False);` to the second example if you'd really like to see the `x`. :)